# Simple Admin Page: Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, admin

I'm thinking of creating admin page with forms to modify, delete and add content to simple pages of website. What would you recommend me to approach this in Symfony2?

Should I create new Bundle or just new Action in same controller where all the other pages are.

I heard of this `SonataAdmin`, but I am not sure I need something this complicated. My admin page will only contain few forms to modify some data that is stored on website. I don't need CMS functionality to create pages or posts.

All I want is simple, safe admin page and to know how nowadays this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create something like a AdminBundle and create your forms there.
Secure your routes so that you need to login to acces that routes.

SonataAdmin is to much for this kind of work.

Example of a secured function where you need to be logged in as admin :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage", name="homepage")
 * @Route("/{_locale}", name="homepage", name="homepage")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 * @Template("ProdacomMainBundle:Main:index.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction() {
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really don't need SonataAdminBundle. It's huge and sometime difficult to understand. So, for such functionality you can create some secured area in your routing and use to access management pages. Or you can implement simple authentication with hardcoded (inside config files) credentials (look detailed description here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) and show for authenticated user additional elements on the pages (forms, buttons, etc.). It really depends on your wishes. I think you have to overthink all you have and just decide which way is more convenient for you.